# Differential equation: $(2x-y^2)y'=2y$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve the ODE $$(2x-y^2)y'=2y$$
This ODE is under the title of ["Variation of parameters"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#Examples) method, but I can't bring it to the form $y'+p(x)y=q(x)$. I suspect that a change of variables should be applied. The $y^2$ hints that I should try $u=y^2$. That gives:
$$\\(2x-y^2)yy'=2y^2
\\(2x-u)\frac{u}{2}=u
\\ 2x-uu'=2u$$
but I can't see how it helps me.

Suggestions will be welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: your solution containes the Bessel function

Comment: yes that is, i have written $(2x^2-y^2)y'=2y$ sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the equation in the following manner :

$$2y \frac{dx}{dy} = 2x-y^2 \\
\frac{dx}{dy}-\frac{x}{y} = -\frac{y}{2}$$

See a linear equation? Use the integration factor $e^{-\ln(y)} = \frac{1}{y}$ to get:

$$\frac{x}{y}=-\frac{y}{2} +C$$

Comment: Actually no, I don't see a linear equation. Are you suggesting a substitution?

Comment: @35T41 You know $y'+p(x)y=q(x)$ is a linear equation?

Comment: Yes. (more characters)

Comment: @35T41 Still don't see it? Replace $x$ with $y$ and $y$ with $x$ in last equation to get it into *your desired* form.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know such a thing is acceptable. It's only my second week as an ODE "solver"... thanks

Comment: @35T41 No I meant $x,y$ are just variables. Working with $y'$ was more comfortable for me too rather than $x'$ in the beginning. Then it became a habit :)

Answer (score 3):

your equation depends on $y$ as independent variable and $x$ is a dependent one, first of all you have to devide both sides with $\frac{dx}{dy}$ so:

$$2x-y^2 = 2yx'$$

then: $$2yx'-2x=-y^2$$

then solve:

$$2yx' - 2x = 0$$

$$2yx' = 2x$$

which is with separable variables:

$$\int\frac{dx}{x} = \int \frac{dy}{y}$$

which gives you

$$\ln|x| = \ln|y|+C$$

or getting rid of $\ln$

$$x = y\cdot C$$

---

and apply Lagrange's method:

$$x(y) = y \cdot C(y)$$

find its derivative:

$$x'(y) = C'(y)y + C(y)$$

then you can substitute it back into your equation (this step very well indicates if you did everything right, cause there's always something with $C$ to reduce):

$$2y^2C'(y)+2yC(y)-2yC(y) = -y^2 \Rightarrow 2y^2C'(y) = -y^2$$

therefore the integral will be:

$$C(y) = -2\int dy \Rightarrow C(y) = -2y + \alpha$$
finally substitute it into $$x= y \cdot C(y)$$

we get:

$$x = -y(2y -\alpha)$$

Comment: How did you get $2yx' - 2x = 0$ from $2yx' - 2x = -y^2$ in line three where you show it to be variable separable ?

Comment: @samjoe, [Variation of parameters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters) ? (see examples)

Comment: Thanks for this method, added something to my knowledge :)